# Plugin Bundle ID conflict in creating a gear VR project in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, gear-vr

i am new to the gear vr .. i tried to build my project but i am getting an error

1. Plugin Bundle ID conflict detected
2. UnityException: Plugin Bundle ID conflict detected!

Plugin Bundle ID conflict detected: package com.oculus.Integration has conflicts with other plugins (Com vs com). Make sure you use the same case for your package names.
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

UnityException: Plugin Bundle ID conflict detected!
Package com.oculus.Integration has conflicts with other plugins. See the Console for details.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuildPointToConsole (System.String title, System.String message)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckLibrariesConflict.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:176)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

how can i resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i removed the error by

select - player settings... inside that
select identifier...inside that
bundle identifier - change its name to your custom company name and product name